# Excel Range Count within a cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, find, comparison

I am trying to compare qty and number of entries in an excel spreadsheet.

For instance,

```
QTY RefDes      # of Entries    QTY Match RefDes?
3   R1,R5,R22   3               MATCH
3   C1,C2,C3    3               MATCH
3   U1-U3       1               MISMATCH
4   U1-U3, U5   2               MISMATCH
```

By using `=LEN(TRIM(B2))-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(B2),",",""))+1` for the column listed # of Entries, I can easily compare the listed QTY vs. ReDes when the values individually are separated by commas as in R1,R5,R22.

(QTY Match RefDes? is simply comparing if the QTY column matches the # of Entries column.)

However, I also have cases where U1-U3 would denote a range from U1 to U3 or U1,U2,U3. The actual quantity is 3, but the formula above returns a value of 1 because there is no comma separation. How can I account for this case?

Comment: Most likely this will require vba.

Comment: I guess it would be best to convert the U1-U3 into U1,U2,U3 ?

Comment: Is there an easy way to convert U1-U3 to U1,U2,U3?

Comment: One-time, use VBA. Going forward, use data validation to force entries to be In comma format

Answer (score 1):

This CAN be done with a formula, but there is a caveat.

Excel has a handy function called EVALUATE(), that evaluates text strings as equations and produces a numeric result.  The caveat has to do with the restrictions on how it can be used.

I guessed that your ranges in Column U could be any size, so a good way to get the count would be to do the subtraction. i.e. for U1-U3, extract the "1-3" and do the math.  This formula does that:

```
 =IFERROR(ABS(EVALUATE((REPLACE(MID(B2,FIND("-",B2)-1,4),3,1,"")))),0)
```

Using B5 as an example, the MID() portion gets characters on either side of the "-", and gives 1-U3. The REPLACE() removes the U, and EVALUATE() performs the subtraction, giving -2. ABS() gives 2 and IFERROR() handles the rows with no U range.  Here is the data with the above equation in Column E, and the sum of this column plus your equation above in Column F:

[image]

Now about the caveat.  For whatever reason, EVALUATE() is ONLY available if it is used in the definition of a named range.  So to use the above equation, click on any cell, give the cell a name (I used "Funk" here), and paste the equation into the "Refers to:" box.

[image]

Now the name can be used like a function. Type "=Funk" (with no quotes) in E2 and fill down.

If you can't have the helper column, you could combine the two equations in the name definition.  But I'll warn you that troubleshooting formulas in the little box is a PITA.  It's a shame this function isn't available without jumping through these hoops.

I hope this helps.

Comment: *For whatever reason, EVALUATE() is ONLY available if it is used in the definition of a named range.* Strictly speaking, it is not an Excel function.  It is actually an Excel 4.0 Macro function (also known as XLM4).  So, for example, it cannot be stored in a .xlsx file.  Other XLM4 macros can also be used via this same method of "Defined Name"

Comment: Yes, thanks for pointing that out. I could have done a better job of explaining that, I guess. I view these XLM4s as dinosaurs that haven't died off yet.  But I still think this would be a useful "real" function to have in Excel. I've seen two questions here in the last week that could be handled with EVALUATE().

Comment: Who knows how MS makes their decisions about these kinds of issues.  I won't hold my breath :-), especially since it is also a VBA function.